# How to debug ctypes without error message

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

I have a simple python script that uses a c/c++ library with `ctypes`. My c++ library also contains a main method, so I can compile it without the `-shared` flag and it can be excecuted and it runs without issues.

However, when I run the same code from a python script using `ctypes`, a part of the c++ program is excecuted (I can tell that from the `cout` calls). Then the entire  application, including the python script, termiantes (I can tell that from the missing `cout` and `print` calls). There is no error message, no segfault, no python stacktrace.

My question is: How can I debug this? What are possible reasons for this to happen?

Here is part of the code, however, since there is no error message, I don't know which code is relevant.

```
import ctypes

interface = ctypes.CDLL("apprunner.so")
interface.start()
print "complete"
```

.

```
#include "../../app/ShaderApp.cpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "TestApp.cpp"

TestApp* app = 0;

extern "C" void start() {
    app = new TestApp();
    cout << "Running from library" << endl;
    app->run();
}

int main( int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    cout << "Running from excecutable" << endl;
    start();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you begin from a small mock-up library that just lets you test the function calls from python. When this is ready (all the debug prints are ok) you proceed further. In your example, comment out #include "testapp.cpp" and get the prints to cout working.

Comment: I did that, the place where it fails doesn't do anything special (just a for loop). Also, the same code works when it's not being called from ctypes.

Comment: Good. Then it's the time to use a debugger (gdb for example). Set a breakpoint in the c++ function. Unfortunately, using a debugger is not easy.

Comment: This solved my problem. The issue was that I was using an array of pointers and not initializing it. When compiling as an excecutable, the array somehow only contained nullpointers, which my code handled correctly.